# Creating a plugin/adapter interface in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, plugins, adapter, system

I need to create a very simple plugin system for my PHP (Symfony, if it matters) app which would allow third party developers to create additional functionality in the form of PHP classes, put it in a specific folder, and have them be loaded up and used by my app. And I'm trying to figure out what is the easiest and best way to go about doing this.

Lets say the plugin should provide 1 public external method that returns some data formatted in a specific way (so it should use an interface or a model created in my app).

1. How would I go about 'enabling' this plugin in my app, and having it load this external class and use the aforementioned public method?
2. How do I do this in a way so that types (classes, interfaces) from my app can be used in the plugin class?

Comment: I think it would make sense to use Symfony's bundle system for this. Include the parts of your app that the third party developers would need in a bundle, then they can require that in their bundles.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve,   this see;s like aa case for interfaces, but might even be a nice case for tagged symfony services, but it depends on what you need ...

Comment: Lets say the app has a page where it outputs text from a function "getText()" and this getText() method would be provided by the plugin. Just an example, but how would I achieve this?